# Thrust library - how to write a wrapper?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sorting, thrust

I have a VS2010 project written in C++ and want to use the thrust::sort functions.  My data is currently in a POD (Plain Old Date) struct.  The thrust::sort routines require a host and device vector container to work.  What's the easiest way to interface my POD data for use by thrust::sort?

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 1):

The very first page of the Thrust user guide gives an example to do exactly that:

```
thrust::host_vector<int> hv = populate();        // make data on host

thrust::device_vector<int> dv(hv.begin(), hv.end()); // copy to device

thrust::sort(dv.begin(), dv.end());              // sort on device

thrust::copy(dv.begin(), dv.end(), hv.begin());  // copy back
```

Instead of `int` you can use your own POD structure, and you can pass a comparator to the sort algorithm.

Comment: Kerrek, thanks for the tip. I cannot find the "user guide" and this example.  I see the "Quickstart Guide" and the Wiki pages.  Where do I find the "User Guide"?

Comment: Hm, maybe I meant the quick start guide... but the API documentation is [online](http://wiki.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/html/modules.html), and it should contain all your algorithms.